# twitter follower

Tags: ruby

I want twitter's follower ID and follower Name.
A User have fowllower have 30,000 or more.
Error output　『Rate limit exceeded (Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests)』.

Please coached me.

```
require "rubygems"
require "twitter"

target = "hogehoge"


client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key = "XXXXX"
    config.consumer_secret = "XXXX"
    config.access_token = "XX-XXXX"
    config.access_token_secret = "XXXXX"
end

followers_list = client.followers(target)
friends_list = client.friends(target)

followers_list.each{|follower|
    puts follower.screen_name
    puts follower.name
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that this is `ja,stackoverflow`, not the main [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)? Unless there is any specific reason (e.g. question about softwares mostly used in Japanese communities), it's recommended to post on stackoverflow if you are more familiar with English than Japanese.

Comment: As for the question itself, I think the error explains itself: [there are too many requests](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting). If you have further questions, please edit the question so that others can understand what exactly you want to know and what you've tried, what you think you might have to do, etc.

Comment: あ，でも hogehoge とか使っていらっしゃるのか．質問は日本語で大丈夫ですよ（そのための ja.stackoverflow）．

Answer (score 1):

### en

You can not get 30000+ users without interval.
Maybe `rate_limit.reset_in` will aid it.

By the way...
`client.followers` called API by each 20(Max:200) users[1].
but
`client.follower_ids` can get 5,000 Ids[2] and `client.users` can lookup 100 users [3]. -- I think better it.

### ja

30,000ユーザーを超えユーザー情報を、インターバル無しで取得することは、できません。
おそらく`rate_limit.reset_in`が助けとなるでしょう。

ところで。
`client.followers`は、20(最大200)ユーザー毎に、APIを呼び出します[1]。
しかし
`client.follower_ids`は、5,000のIDを取得できますし[2]。`client.users`は、100ユーザーの情報を、参照できます[3]。―― こっちのほうがより良いと思いますよ。

### see also

[1] https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list
* 200users x 15(30)req / 15min = 3,000(6,000)users / 15min

vs.

[2] https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids
* 5,000IDs x 15(15)req / 15min = 7,500(7,500)IDs / 15min
[3] https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup
* 100users x 180(60)req / 15min = 18,000(6,000)users / 15min.